# Scraping a range of urls on a server for images

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to scrape a website that contains a large folder at images that is located at the url http://my.aup.edu/files/pictures/picture-35933.jpg using nodejs with cheerio and request. Extracting one image from a page looks something like this

---

```js
var request = require("request"),
    cheerio = require("cheerio"),
    urls = [];
request('', function(err, resp, body){
    if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200 ) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('body.img').each(function(){
           var url = $(this).attr("src");
            urls.push(url);
        
        });
        
        console.log(urls)
    }
    
});
```

This program accomplishes logging the url to the console but it will not save the picture. However the file extensions on the site are kind of weird because even though the link is http://my.aup.edu/files/pictures/picture-35933.jpg not all of the extensions 1-99999 have images.. some just redirect to a different page. Could I use an if statement with a math.random() at the end of the url to check if it contains an img and then download it. Please let me know if this is possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

well if you perform a http HEAD request instead of a http GET you could then look at the content-type and (hopefully) find out if you have a image or not.